# PrimeNg editable table save enter keyboard

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

How can I save a row with ENTER key on an editable table where I navigate through columns with TAB key ? I ușe a form... any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your questions correctly. PrimeFaces != PrimeNG, read the tag content.

Comment: Yep...I am refering to www.primefaces.org/primeng table

Comment: Correct that is PrimeNG, not PrimeFaces (the technology, not the site). If you ask a Java question you also do not tag it 'Oracle' even though all documentation is on the Oracle site... Cheers.